# How to programattically access parameter prompts in DialogFlow

Tags: dialogflow-es

I have a basic lead gen bot under which I have 2 services (in 2 different intents) for which I am collecting leads. Under both of them I am collecting the name, email, and phone number and I also have checked the required tick boxes.

It's working as expected when I am just availing/submitting lead for a single service. However, if in the same interaction I also want to go for the second service the bot is again asking for the name, email & phone number which it already has from my interaction for the first service. How do I make sure that it doesn't ask for the details if it already has them?

I also do not mind handling it programmatically using fulfillment but I could not find any documentation.

Any help is highly appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use the user storage (https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/save-data)
or alternatively you can try to link the parameters of the two intents to the same context parameters. Set your parameter value like this `#context_name.param_name`

Comment: Thank you, I was able to control the behavior as I wanted using contexts

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this by setting an output context in the first intent & using the input context in the second intent.

The trick was to assign a **default value** to the parameters in the second intent as "context_name.param"